# slideToggle how to check whether it's opened or closed

Tags: jquery

I'm using slideToggle for a div. How i can check whether the slide is opened or closed?

Comment: Tags and greetings not required

Comment: `$('#yourDiv').is(':visible')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use

`$('#divId').is(':visible');`

Answer (score 1):

You can try below:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#content').slideToggle('slow', function () {
        if ($('#contentDetail2').is(':hidden')) {
            // some code when content is hidden
        }
        else {
            // some code when content is shown
        }
    });       
});
```